# Is there a way to translate $\forall x(x=x)$ into unambiguous, colloquial English?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is there a way to translate $\forall x(x=x)$ into unambiguous, colloquial English?

This is without a stated domain.

Thinking perhaps it would be something like simply everything is the same as itself.

Comment: I'd model "Everything is the same" as $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$, not $\forall x(x=x)$.

Comment: @GitGud  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DR30nKnE80g

Comment: @WillJagy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrEFqpnbrxY

Comment: How about "Everything is Everything!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with "Everything is the same as itself."

Comment: You could exchange "the same" with "interchangeable".

Answer (score 2):

"For each individual thing, it is true that it is equal to itself."

I've translated it this way, albeit there is actually a lot of published content on stating "P" vs. stating "It's true that P", e.g. claiming "I am human." vs. claiming "It's true that I am human."

Comment: It seems to me when you say 'each' individual thing it could be interpreted as slightly ambiguous, as in could not encompass 'all' things, though I like your translation

Comment: what about 'each and every thing is equal/identical to itself)

Comment: @rmw: I don't understand your first sentence. Why does the word 'each' possibly leave out something? Why is it weaker than 'all'?